# Representing a constant symbol in Sympy such that it is not a free_symbol

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

**Application**
I want to create a python function (e.g., `Laplacian(expr)`). The Laplacian operator is defined as taking the sum of the second partial derivatives of `expr` with respect to each variable (e.g., `Laplacian(f(x,y,z))` is `diff(f,x,x) + diff(f,y,y) + diff(f,z,z)`. In the expression, there may be arbitrary constants `c`,`k`, etc that are not variables as far as the expression is concerned. Just as you cannot take the derivative `diff(f,126)`, taking the derivative of the expression with respect to `c` is not defined.

**Need** I need to be able to extract the non-constant free symbols from an expression.

**Problem**
Though I can construct `c = Symbol('c', constant=True, number=True)` in Sympy, `c.is_constant()` evaluates to `False`. Similarly, `g(c).is_constant()` evaluates to false. For my application, the symbol `c` should have the exact same behavior as `E.is_constant() == True` and `g(E).is_constant() == True`, as it is a number.

**Caveats**

1. I cannot register `c` as a singleton, as it is only defined with respect to this particular proof or expression.
2. I cannot construct it in the same way values like `E` are constructed, as there is no specific numeric value for it to be assigned to.
3. I cannot simply add a `constants` keyword to `Laplacian`, as I do not know all such constants that may appear (just as  it would not make sense to add `constants=[1,2,3,4,...]` to `solve()`).
4. I cannot simply add a `variables` keyword to `Laplacian`, as I do not know the variables that appear in the expression.

The desired usage is as follows:

```
>>> C = ... # somehow create the constant
>>> symbols_that_arent_constant_numbers(g(C))
set()
>>> symbols_that_arent_constant_numbers(g(C, x))
{x}
>>> g(C).is_constant()
True
```

**stretch goals:** It would be awesome to have an arbitrary constant symbol that absorbs other constant terms in the same way that `constantsimp` operates. Consider introducing an integration constant `c` into an expression, and then multiplying that expression by `I`. As far as we are concerned algebraically, `cI=c` without loosing any generality.

Comment: Why don't you want the symbol to appear in free symbols?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin, I've gone ahead and edited the question to add a motivating example as well as additional desiderata for a solution, if at all possible.

Comment: Would something like this help? https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18497

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Both of the proposed introduced mechanisms seem to be applicable. `ArbitraryConstant` seems to exactly manage the stretch goals I mention above. `Quantity` has been an acceptable workaround, but it's lacking the algebraic simplifications and seem to introduce rendering artifacts (quantities are always displayed last). I +1'd the issue and its related issue.

Comment: You'd be more aware than I am, but [5040](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/5040) and [4435](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/4435) also appear related. Great to see the contributors active on SO!

Comment: I imagine that in all cases the constants will still appear in `expr.free_symbols` though. It's not clear to me why you want the symbol not to be listed as a free symbol.

Comment: I'd like to write a python function `maththing(expr)` that operates on an expression. I'd like to be able to ignore constants. Setting `Symbol('k', constant=True, number=True)` has no effect on `k.is_constant()`, so there is no way to filter out these values. I cannot pass a `constants` argument into `maththing(expr)`, because I don't know what the constants are ahead of time. The constants aren't "free", because the expression does not vary with respect to them. (i.e., `d/dx( 1 ) = 0`). They are exactly a number.

Comment: It sounds like your original problem might have a better solution than the question as posed here

Comment: Rephrased question to be more clear as to the exact need.

Comment: I would tell Laplacian which symbols to differentiate wrt to: `Laplacian(f(x, y, z), [x, y, z])`. Or otherwise you could make global symbols, x, y, z, r, theta, etc and make sure those are always used for the relevant coordinates in any expressions.

Comment: I don't/shouldn't have that information at the point where `Laplacian` is to be called. All I have is the expression. Fixing a symbol to an arbitrary point is extremely common. Even if I were to explicitly tell `Laplacian` to ignore it, consider the use cases in my answer. Given the context of `c`, it's mathematically incorrect to say `g(c)` is non-constant. The motivating example is just an example.

Comment: I think that the mistake is having the expression without knowing what the variables are. This question feels very much like an XY problem to me: a new question based on the *original* problem would be more productive.

Comment: `solve(x*y/exp(8 + x))` yields solutions for both `x` and `y` without (1) knowing what variables are part of the expression _a priori_ and (2) without attempting to substitute values in place of `e`. If the library is incapable of allowing clients to develop code with an API consistent with the library, it's not the fault of the client for wanting to. _This is the original problem_ I need to solve; it's been rewritten only to make it clear.

Comment: `solve` needs to be told which of the symbols are the unknowns. For convenience you can call `solve` without specifying the unknowns which is nice for interactive work in simple unambiguous cases. That's not a good API for serious use though and I would *always* call solve with the unknowns specified.

Answer (score 5):

**Note**

Per Oscar Benjamin's comments on question, current best practices when constructing a sympy-style method (like `Laplacian`) is to pass a `constants` or `variables` keyword into a method. Bare that in mind when applying the following solution. Furthermore, `free_symbols` has many applications within Sympy, so using another class that has established semantics may have unexpected side-effects.

(I am not accepting my own solution in the event that a better one comes along, as Mr. Benjamin has pointed out there are many open related issues.)

**Solution**

Sympy provides a mechanism to create such a constant: [`sympy.physics.units.quantities.Quantity`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/units/quantities.html). Its behavior is equivalent to `Symbol` and singleton constants, but most notably it does not appear as a free symbol. This can help prevent code from interpreting it as a variable that may be differentiated, etc.

```
from sympy.physics.units.quantities import Quantity
C = Quantity('C')

print("C constant?        : ", C.is_constant())
print("C free symbols     : ", C.free_symbols)
print("x constant?        : ", x.is_constant())
print("g(C) constant?     : ", g(C).is_constant())
print("g(x) constant?     : ", g(x).is_constant())
print("g(C,x) constant    : ", g(C,x).is_constant())
print("g(C) free symbols  : ", g(C).free_symbols)
print("g(C,x) free symbols: ", g(C,x).free_symbols)

assert C.is_constant()
assert C.free_symbols == set([])
assert g(C).is_constant()
assert g(C, x).is_constant() == g(x).is_constant() # consistent interface
assert g(C).free_symbols == set([])
assert g(C, x).free_symbols == set([x])
assert [5/C] == solve(C*x -5, x)
```

The above snippet produces the following output when tested in `sympy==1.5.1`:

```
C constant?        :  True
C free symbols     :  set()
x constant?        :  False
g(C) constant?     :  True
g(x) constant?     :  None
g(C,x) constant    :  None
g(C) free symbols  :  set()
g(C,x) free symbols:  {x}
```

Note that while `g(C).is_constant()==True`, we see that `g(x).is_constant() == None`, as well as `g(C,x).is_constant() == None`. Consequently, I only assert that those two applications have a consistent interface.